# TD learning Equivalence of Forward and Backward Views

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In [this tutorial](http://incompleteideas.net/book/first/ebook/node76.html), the author explained, in TD learning, why forward view equals to backward view. I did not understand the equation shown below. How did $\gamma\lambda V_t(s_{t+1})$ turn into $V_t(s_{t})$ ? (From equation 1 to 2 )

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take the first $-V_t(s_t)$ and insert it in the line below to replace $-\lambda \gamma V_t(s_{t+1}))$, which you insert in the next line, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! Turns out to be a math question lol